# Fourier Series of a decaying Cosine

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to find a handy way to find the infinite sum

$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos( a n)}{n^2} $

through a Fourier series. The regular sum can be evaluated using Mathematica fairly easily, and gives a result of 
$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos( a n)}{n^2} = 0.324138$, found through some Polylogs.

The idea would be to FT $\frac{cos( a n)}{n^2}$ and evaluate the sum in reciprocal space but this isn't yielding anything good. I can get the FT no problem but when I sum over the reciprocal lattice vectors the sum diverges. I'm using $ \vec{a} = l \hat{x} $ for real space vectors, where $l=1$ is the separation of sampling sites, and $\vec{b} = \frac{1}{l} \hat{x} $ for reciprocal space vectors. It's fairly easy to see from the Fourier Transform F from real space to reciprocal space ($t$ - bad choice I know) that

$ {F} (\frac{cos( a n)}{n^2}) \to \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi/2} (Sign[1 - t] + t Sign[-1 + t] + Sign[1 + t] + 
   t Sign[1 + t]) $

so will diverge when doing the sum over t (which goes as 1/n right?), as this Fourier Transformed sum now goes as the harmonic series.

Can anyone see where I've slipped up in my reasoning? Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

This can be evaluated using [the  polylogarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) $\mathrm{Li}_2$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(an)}{n^2}
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ian}}{n^2}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\mathrm{Li}_2(e^{ia})\right)\\[2pt]
&=\frac12\left(\mathrm{Li}_2(e^{ia})+\mathrm{Li}_2(e^{-ia})\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Note that the derivative of $(1)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(an)}{n}
&=-\mathrm{Im}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ian}}{n}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\log\left(1-e^{ia}\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&=\frac{a-\pi}{2}\quad\text{on }(0,2\pi)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Integrating $(2)$ and noting that $(1)$ is $-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ at $a=\pi$ yields that on $(0,2\pi)$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(an)}{n^2}
=\left(\frac{a-\pi}{2}\right)^2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\tag{3}
$$

**Plot of one period:**

$\hspace{2mm}$[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the way Mathematica solves it and something I've found analytically. I am trying to see if this can be solved through summing in momentum-space however it's been a while since I did any Fourier stuff!

Comment: @Josh: when I plotted this, I realized that it was a parabola. I have added the proof of this.